# Transpose geographic coordinates to Unity coordinate system

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I'm making a game that works only in a fixed geographical area. The custom I'm making the game for wants to a Pokémon Go-like user interface. There will be a place with a custom image representing the geographical area I was taking about.
I successfully transposed the geographic coordinates to cartesian coordinate with the following code:

```
cartesianCoord.x = EARTH_RADIUS * Mathf.Cos (location.latitude) * Mathf.Cos (location.longitude);
cartesianCoord.y = EARTH_RADIUS * Mathf.Cos (location.latitude) * Mathf.Sin (location.longitude);
cartesianCoord.z = EARTH_RADIUS * Mathf.Sin (location.latitude);
```

But now I can't properly place my character on the place.
This represents my situation: (red dots are known)
[image]

The image on the left is my plane in Unity.
How can I place the character in the right position on the plane?

Comment: You need to know the projection used for the map.

Answer (score -1):

You should use linear interpolation.

[Mathf.Lerp documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html)

Comment: Linear interpolation will at best be an approximation.